# Questions about impact velocity angle

Tags: calculus, physics

The question describes a projectile launched from ground at an angle of $40$ degrees with an initial velocity of $96$ ft/s.
I understand the concept of resolving this $96$ into x and y components.
So, I can easily answer the questions of Max height (59.5 ft), how long will it take for the thing to hit the ground ($3.86 s$) and the range or max horizontal distance ($283.6$ ft).  **However, it then asks for the impact velocity.**  I now see how the $V_(xf)=V_(xi)$ since the $a_x=0$ and how $V_(yf)=V_(yi)$, however I don't see how this angle is $140$ degrees.  I do see how the $V_f$ is negative, but I don't see how we can just arbitrarily assign $140$ degrees to make the final velocity negative.  How do I mathematically show the angle is in Q2?

How ***do*** I get the impact angle?

Comment: For an object launched vertically upwards, what is the relation between, at the same horizontal height, of the object while going upwards, and coming back down?

Comment: It would seem to me that the x direction is to the right and the vertical direction at impact is downward, so that would put the angle in Q4 and the angle would be 320 not 140. I don't see how this angle becomes 140.

Comment: I'm confused in your question about horizontal height.  Did you mean vertical height?

Comment: Oops, I meant at a particular vertical height

Comment: the theta would be the same

Comment: so wouldn't that mean the final velocity would have the same angle = 40 degrees.  but, book said 140 degrees.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The impact speed is just the launch speed (by energy conservation), and the angle is $-40^\circ$. Because the $x$ component velocity is the same, and the $y$ component reversed. However, if you define the impact velocity as the angle between the trajectory with the +ve $x$ axis at the moment when it hits the ground, then $140^\circ$ is also ok (if it is from a physics textbook :) ). But I would say $-40^\circ$ (or $320^\circ$) is more correct mathematically.

Comment: YESSS....I would think the angle would be $320$ or $-40$, NOT $140$

Comment: It would be a Q4 angle.

Comment: No, it's from a calculus class.

Comment: Mathematically, it should be $-40^\circ$ or $320^\circ$. But I think $140^\circ$ is an acceptable answer in physics.

Comment: Why does 140 work in physics?

Comment: It's the angle between the tangent line (no direction) of the trajectory with the +ve $x$ axis at the moment it hits the ground.

Comment: OK, I can see that.

Comment: Actually, I'm a physicist, and I'd call it just $40$.

Comment: @NickPavlov Sorry, not meant to offense. Actually I am a physics student.

Comment: @velutluna I wasn't taking offense, just thought I'd throw my two cents in... I guess I really wanted to say that the whole debate seems kind of moot, but I need to work on my expressiveness, probably.